# Graph visualization for web

Tags: graph, visualization, web

Who can advise any solutions for graph visualization for web.
I need to use it on my home web-site.

For example image of function y = x^2 + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at java applet :
http://xxi.ac-reims.fr/javamaths/Grapheur/PetitGrapheur.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to contact the author of this page:

http://silentmatt.com/javascript-function-plotter/

Another alternative:

http://syzygy.virtualave.net/webwork/javascript/plotter.htm

And a third one:

http://fooplot.com/